# pdftk + xfdf + php can't handle umlauts

Tags: php, pdf, acrobat, pdftk, xfdf

I'm using XFDF files to fill out PDF-forms serverside with PHP and pdftk but my problem is that no non-english characters (ä, ö, å etc.) are printed to the form fields.

Here is the function I use to parse the XFDF file:

```
function createFDF($file,$info,$enc='UTF-8'){ 
$data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.$enc.'"?>'."\n". 
    '<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">'."\n". 
    '<fields>'."\n"; 
foreach($info as $field => $val){ 
    $data.='<field name="'.$field.'">'."\n"; 
    if(is_array($val)){ 
        foreach($val as $opt) 
            $data.='<value>'.htmlentities($opt,ENT_COMPAT,$enc).'</value>'."\n"; 
    }else{ 
        $data.='<value>'.htmlentities($val,ENT_COMPAT,$enc).'</value>'."\n"; 
    } 
    $data.='</field>'."\n"; 
} 
$data.='</fields>'."\n". 
    '<ids original="'.md5($file).'" modified="'.time().'" />'."\n". 
    '<f href="'.$file.'" />'."\n". 
    '</xfdf>'."\n"; 
return $data;
```

And the resulting XFDF file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
<fields>
<field name="loadman-pudotuspainolaitteen-mittaustulosten-tallenne">
<value>1201</value>
</field>
<field name="tutkittavarakenne-rivi1">
<value>a</value>
</field>
<field name="tutkittavarakenne-rivi2">
<value></value>
</field>
<field name="tutk-pvm">
<value>11.12.2012</value>
</field>
<field name="mittauksen_suorittaja">
<value>o</value>
</field>
<field name="vast-tyonjohtaja">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="rakennemateriaali">
<value>&auml;</value>
</field>
<field name="laatuvaatimukset">
<value>&aring;</value>
</field>
<field name="mittauspaikan_tiivistysmenetelma">
<value>&aacute;</value>
</field>
<field name="pohjalevy">
<value>&eacute;</value>
</field>
<field name="pohjamaa-alusrakenne">
<value>&iacute;</value>
</field>
<field name="mittauspaikan-tiivistysmenetelma">
<value>&egrave;</value>
</field>
<field name="emoduli">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="tiiveys">
<value>&ouml;&auml;</value>
</field>
<field name="huomautukset_ja_loppupaatelmat1">
<value>&ouml;&auml;</value>
</field>
<field name="huomautukset_ja_loppupaatelmat2">
<value>&ouml;&auml;</value>
</field>
<field name="huomautukset_ja_loppupaatelmat3">
<value>&ouml;&auml;</value>
</field>
<field name="empa1">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="empa1-e">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="empa2">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="empa2-e">
<value>&ouml;</value>
</field>
<field name="allekirjoitus">
<value>Einomies Porkkakoski</value>
</field>
</fields>
<ids original="84b0ff7a04b017303be186faa0d1254a" modified="1343290963" />
<f href="assets/loadman.pdf" />
</xfdf>
```

The fields with english letters print perfectly but letters with acutes, graves or scandinavian additions wont transfer to the PDF file. 
**EXCEPT** for some reason

```
<field name="huomautukset_ja_loppupaatelmat1">
<value>&ouml;&auml;</value>
</field>
```

works perfectly and prints öä!

The command I run is

```
pdftk <pdf-file> fill_form <xfdf-file> output <output file> flatten
```

This does not result any errors.

I'm using Debian 6.0, PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze13 and the pdftk version is 1.44-5

**UPDATE** I noticed that if I don't flatten the generated file and open it, the characters are printed correctly when the field is activated but hidden again when the field is unfocused. If I manually type anything to the file, the special characters will show up also. Saved and reopened file however doesn't show the text unless again some text is added.

**UPDATE 2** Got the damn thing fixed. Originally the forms were made with Adobe Acrobat Pro on OSX Snow Leopard. Now I remade the forms with LibreOffice + Oracle PDF Import plugin and everything seems to be working!

Comment: Having the same issue filling a PDF(created in LibreOffice Writer) with PDFTK.
In the exported pdf i can not write a non-latin character,i exported with the built in pdf exporter

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have more luck if you use the following list:

- `&#196;` for Ä (instead of `&Auml;`)
- `&#197;` for Å (instead of `&Aring;`)
- `&#214;` for Ö (instead of `&Ouml;`)
- `&#220;` for Ü (instead of `&Uuml;`)
- `&#223;` for ß (instead of `&szlig;`)
- `&#228;` for ä (instead of `&auml;`)
- `&#229;` for å (instead of `&aring;`)
- `&#246;` for ö (instead of `&ouml;`)
- `&#252;` for ü (instead of `&uuml;`)

I'll let you yourself find out how to extend that list until it reaches completeness :-)

Comment: Funnily enough there recently was a discussion on the Unicode mailing list coming to the conclusion that character references are largely unnecessary nowadays ;-). But indeed, HTML entities are definitely wrong for an XML format.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use `htmlentities` in your PHP script. That converts the accented symbols to `&xxxx;`

Set your XML encoding to `iso-8859-1` or `WINDOWS-1252` and leave out the `htmlentities` in your PHP script

*Another thing to try is to use* `utf8_encode` *instead of* `htmlentities` *(and not modify the XML-encoding)*

Comment: So I changed the encoding to ISO-8859-1 and removed the `htmlentities`. Now ä results `<value>Ã¤</value>` in the XFDF file and the value is printed just simply ¤. What am I not understanding?

Comment: I used utf8_decode() to change `<value>Ã¤</value>` to `<value>ä</value>` but now again the character won't print to the field.

Answer (score 0):

To support any UFT-8 characters, I wrote PdfFormFillerUTF-8: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfformfiller2/

Comment: Hi Nikolay, thanks for your answer and welcome to Stack Overflow. A small tip when writing answers: it's usually better to include an explanation of your answer rather than just a link. That way, if the link ever moves or breaks, the answer will still be useful.