# pdftk fill_form utf8 problems

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, pdftk, fdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten FDF / XFDF forms to PDF in PHP with utf-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973283/flatten-fdf-xfdf-forms-to-pdf-in-php-with-utf-8-characters)

I am using pdftk to fill template pdf with data from fdf.  Data has correct utf-8 characters, but when I use fill_form, resulting pdf file has formating errors. (I am **NOT** using `flatten`)

I have problems with letters like `š`, `đ`, `č`, `ć`, `ž`.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
**My solution**

In the end, I gave up on pdftk, I ended up using [fpfd](http://www.fpdf.org/), to be more precise, I used [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) script. 
I had couple of problems here too, related to the pdf file. But I used pdftk to fix that pdf (as was suggested in the script itself), and in the end it helped me: it filled the pdf form I had with the characters without messing them up.

Answer (score 4):

pdftk (as of v1.44) can't handle chars outside the standard ASCII with FDF form fill. Someone did try to modify pdftk to allow multi-byte characters to support Asian languages, but from the comments I'm not sure it actually works.

http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/07/19/pdftk-supports-chinese-path-now/

**Related Questions:**

[Flatten FDF / XFDF forms to PDF in PHP with utf-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973283/flatten-fdf-xfdf-forms-to-pdf-in-php-with-utf-8-characters)

[pdftk + xfdf + php can't handle umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665394/pdftk-xfdf-php-cant-handle-umlauts)

Comment: So, I should give up on pdftk?
I'm currently looking into [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/), there is a plugin for filling a form, but I still have problems, this time with pdf formatting I believe.
Thanks for your answer!